# Setting up build variable "version" breaks Azure Functions CLI func extensions sync

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

An Azure Function is not building properly using the Azure function CLI command: func extensions sync in an Azure build pipeline written in yaml within which a variable "version" is declared:

```
pool:
  name: Dev
variables:
  version: $(Build.BuildNumber)
steps:
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: "NPM Install function app"
    inputs:
      workingDir: src
      command: install
  - powershell: "dotnet restore"
    workingDirectory: src
  - powershell: "func extensions sync --javascript"
    workingDirectory: src
```

fails at "func extensions sync" call with this error message:

```
Restore completed in 34.26 ms for /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/extensions.csproj.
obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/extensions.AssemblyInfo.cs(12,59): warning CS7035: The specified version string does not conform to the recommended format - major.minor.build.revision [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/extensions.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/extensions.AssemblyInfo.cs(16,55): error CS7034: The specified version string does not conform to the required format - major[.minor[.build[.revision]]] [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/extensions.csproj]

Build FAILED.
```

I know for a fact that the $version variable is set to 20190806.19

The result is that no binaries are loaded in the build artifact which prevents the successful deployment of the Azure Function.

I know that removing the version variable declaration fixes the Azure Function cli call.

This is reproducible locally by setting up a version variable in the environment.

However I need this variable to proceed to replacement in package.json file using the FileTransform task.

It appears that the func extensions sync generates a wrong extensions.AssemblyInfo.cs (here's a sample of the output):

```cs
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Generated by the MSBuild WriteCodeFragment class.
// </auto-generated>    
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute("extensions")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute("Debug")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("20190806.19.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("20190806.19")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute("extensions")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute("extensions")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("20190806.19.0.0")]
```

Is there a workaround?
Is this an issue I could raise in the project GitHub or am I missing some details?

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to set the environment variable after running the extensions sync:

```
- powershell: $env:version=$(Build.BuildNumber)
- task: FileTransform@1
  inputs:
    folderPath: src
    targetFiles: "package.json"
    fileType: json
```

Not super elegant but it works...